# Trying to add multiple items to list in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Basically, I'm trying to add items on a list using an input tag.
The problem is, I add one and whenever I add another, it replaces the first. Help is appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
let save_btn = document.getElementById('Save')
let noteList = document.getElementById('noteList')
let textField = document.getElementById('textField')
const notes = document.createElement('li')


save_btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    notes.textContent = textField.value;
    noteList.appendChild(notes)
    textField.value='' 
})
```

Comment: Move the creation of `notes` inside the listener callback

Comment: I'm so dumb. Thanks a lot, that helped!